# Minimize sum of $w_i(y_i-y)$ given $|y_i-y| \leq 4w_i$

Tags: algorithms

> Given numbers $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ and $w_1,\ldots,w_n > 0$, find $y_c$ which minimizes $$ L = \sum_{i=1}^n w_i (y_i - y) $$
> under the constraint $|y_i - y| \leq 4w_i$.

How to proceed?

Comment: Can you rephrase this problem without the spurious application, which was made up just for the sake of the exercise? One of the cornerstones of computer science is *abstraction*.

Comment: This is a problem dump. What have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Is $y_c$ one of $y_1,\ldots,y_n$?

Comment: It would change the solution.

Comment: I'm sure you can figure it out on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Write
$$ L = \sum_{i=1}^n w_i y_i - \sum_{i=1}^n w_i y. $$
Thus $L$ is linear in $y$, and moreover, it is a decreasing function. Thus we want to choose the largest $y$ which satisfies the constraints $|y_i - y| \leq 4w_i$, if any. I'll let you figure out how to find this $y$.